# Error: Network error while attempting to run command 'saslStart' on host 'localhost:27017'

Tags: mongodb

When I run `mongo` I can able to lists the DBs using `show dbs` command, and perform write and read actions.

But when using the client (Robot 3T) I receive the next error:

```
Error:
Network error while attempting to run command 'saslStart' on host 'localhost:27017'
```

Localhost DB, using macOS Catalina.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I had the same problem today and solved it by upgrading Robo3T from 1.2 to latest 1.3.1.

Comment: I think this problem is with Robo3T 1.2 and Mongo DB V4

Comment: Thanks. Solved it by upgrading Robo3T from 1.2 to latest 1.3.1.

Comment: Robo3t < 1.3 doesn't support Mongodb v4

Comment: Thank you, I upgraded my Robo3T to 1.3, it resolved my problem, I am using the Mongo 4.2.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because of version mismatch between mongoclient and mongo. I was able to reproduce this error by using different versions of mongoclient and mongo.

You need to upgrade your mongoclient in every part of your project including python, node and Robo3T etc.