# Error: error doing query: failed: network error while attempting to run command 'find' on host 'mongo.acme.com:27017'

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I have a mongodb cluster setup on kubernetes using the bitnami helm chart. https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb. You can see my redacted production yaml file here https://pastebin.com/41rc3JC1

Ive had this running for 2-3 weeks now. Ive noticed When i make a query using the cli, **ocassionally** i get the following error:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.streamers.find().pretty()
```

> Error: error doing query:
> failed: network error while attempting to run command 'find' on host
> 'mongo.acme.com:27017'

I connect to mongo using the following url `mongo mongodb://<redacted_username>:<redacted_password>@mongo.acme.com:27017`

```
rs.status
```

```
{
    "set" : "rs0",
    "date" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:40.136Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "term" : NumberLong(3),
    "syncingTo" : "",
    "syncSourceHost" : "",
    "syncSourceId" : -1,
    "heartbeatIntervalMillis" : NumberLong(2000),
    "majorityVoteCount" : 2,
    "writeMajorityCount" : 1,
    "optimes" : {
        "lastCommittedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "lastCommittedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:34.606Z"),
        "readConcernMajorityOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "readConcernMajorityWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:34.606Z"),
        "appliedOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "durableOpTime" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(3)
        },
        "lastAppliedWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:34.606Z"),
        "lastDurableWallTime" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:34.606Z")
    },
    "lastStableRecoveryTimestamp" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
    "lastStableCheckpointTimestamp" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
    "electionCandidateMetrics" : {
        "lastElectionReason" : "electionTimeout",
        "lastElectionDate" : ISODate("2020-09-16T10:27:44.421Z"),
        "electionTerm" : NumberLong(3),
        "lastCommittedOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1600241404, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        "lastSeenOpTimeAtElection" : {
            "ts" : Timestamp(1600241404, 1),
            "t" : NumberLong(2)
        },
        "numVotesNeeded" : 2,
        "priorityAtElection" : 5,
        "electionTimeoutMillis" : NumberLong(10000),
        "numCatchUpOps" : NumberLong(0),
        "newTermStartDate" : ISODate("2020-09-16T10:27:44.439Z"),
        "wMajorityWriteAvailabilityDate" : ISODate("2020-09-16T10:27:44.502Z")
    },
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "a211af6c97d4847519c8a859471a1846-<redacted>.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 3975838,
            "optime" : {
                "ts" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
                "t" : NumberLong(3)
            },
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:34Z"),
            "syncingTo" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1600252064, 1),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2020-09-16T10:27:44Z"),
            "configVersion" : 2,
            "self" : true,
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-0.mongo-prod-mongodb-arbiter-headless.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 7,
            "stateStr" : "ARBITER",
            "uptime" : 2507,
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:39.159Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2020-09-16T11:09:38.700Z"),
            "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
            "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
            "syncingTo" : "",
            "syncSourceHost" : "",
            "syncSourceId" : -1,
            "infoMessage" : "",
            "configVersion" : 2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1,
    "$clusterTime" : {
        "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1),
        "signature" : {
            "hash" : BinData(0,"7pmSYWIweERYYg/QjqIIjQrQmo4="),
            "keyId" : NumberLong("6855964983600087044")
        }
    },
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1600254574, 1)
}
```

As you can see from the yaml this mongodb cluster is exposed to the outside via a loadbalancer which is created on aws. I have then setup a cname which points `mongo.acme.com` to the url of the load balancer.

Why am i getting these occasional network errors? is it something i should be concerned about? Can you see anything Ive misconfigured?

if you need me to provide any more information , please ask.

Comment: Did you introduce any changes lately? Updates, configuration changes, etc? As you mention its `occasional network errors`, how often do they occur?

Comment: Nope no changes recently

Comment: And how often those errors occurs? Its your local env or cloud?

Comment: @PjoterS cloud, I don't think i can give you an accurate answer. Ive noticed it whenever im connected to mongo and making a query.

Comment: Did you try different versions? In similar case [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509937/mongo-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-whatsmyuri-on-host) or [this SO case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595897/error-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-saslstart-on-host-localh) issue was version mismatch. I've also tried to reproduce this behavior but was not able, similar as users on [Github](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/3688)

Comment: @PjoterS Ye it must be different version of shell compared to version of mongodb im connecting to. thanks ill give it ago at syncing that

Comment: Did change of the versions resolved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as `Community Wiki` for better visibility and as `possible root cause` was not confirmed by OP.

Error like:

`failed: network error while attempting to run command 'XXX' on host 'mongo.acme.com:27017'` usually occurs when there is an issue with versions mismatch between `mongo server` and `mongo client shell`.

In the internet can find many examples like [whatismyuri command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509937/mongo-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-whatsmyuri-on-host) or [saslStart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58595897/error-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-saslstart-on-host-localh).

Second most common root cause is attempting to connect without `SSL` to a `MongoDB server` that requires it, like mentioned in [this troubleshoot guide](https://www.aptible.com/documentation/deploy/troubleshooting/mongodb-error.html).

As solution for this kind of issue is to have the same version for `server` and `mongo shell` and make check if `MongoDB` require `SSL connection`.

However, if the problem is more complex, you must double-check the logs.